ORA-02020: too many database links in use
I have been working on a oracle database query that uses more than 4 database links and I keep getting this error ORA-02020: too many database links in use.
I cannot change the limit and tried using CTEs to counter this but still shows errors. How can I run this now? Are CTEs even helpful?

Talk to your DBA to increase it. The default value for this is rather low. Ensure DB-Link is closed after you used it.

Is there a way to close db link within a query? And what about CTEs?

No, you cannot. You can close it only after statement was executed.

Within a query, no.  CTEs are just one of many ways to structure a query but it's all still part of the same query.  If you need more than 4 database links in the query, talk to the DBA to increase the limit.  Or change the logic so that you don't need that many database links in a single query (i.e. use materialized views to replicate the data locally, pull data into temp tables locally and close the database link, etc.)

Sure. Thanks for the information.

In Oracle database, the number of database links that can be opened simultaneously in the same session is limited. This limit is controlled by the parameters open_links and open_links_per_instance. If this limit is exceeded, an ORA-02020 error will be thrown.
If it is necessary to open multiple database connections simultaneously, consider increasing the values of the open_links and open_links_per_instance parameters. This requires the permission of a database administrator.
ALTER SYSTEM SET open_links = 10; -- Default value is 4
ALTER SYSTEM SET open_links_per_instance = 10; -- Default value is 4

